# Unable to save relationship between two objects with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am building a Django/React App to allow users to submit orders that need to go from A to B. The user initially saves the addresses in the database and then he/she selects it in the order form. When they submit I attempt to create a relationship in the database, I'm using Django Rest Framework serializers to create the Order object in the database.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to successfully save the items as I'm not properly linking the addresses to the order. Im getting the following error:

```
destinationAddress: ["Invalid value."]
originAddress: ["Invalid value."]
```

Models

```
class Order(models.Model):
    originAddress = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="originAddress",  null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    destinationAddress = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="destinationAddress",   null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    packages = models.CharField("Packages", max_length=1024)

class Address(models.Model):
    address_code = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    contact = models.CharField("Contact", max_length=1024)
    phone = models.CharField("Phone", max_length=20)
    company = models.CharField("Company", max_length=250)
    addressLine1 = models.CharField("Address line 1", max_length=1024)
    addressLine2 = models.CharField("Address line 2", max_length=1024, blank=True)
    postalCode = models.CharField("Postal Code", max_length=12)
    city = models.CharField("City", max_length=1024)
    state = models.CharField("State", max_length=250)
```

Serializers

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    originAddress = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=Address.objects.all(),
        slug_field='pk'
    )
    destinationAddress = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=Address.objects.all(),
        slug_field='pk'
    )


    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'packages', 'destinationAddress', 'originAddress')
```

ViewSets

```
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]

    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

class AddressViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Address.objects.all()

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]

    serializer_class = AddressSerializer
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `many=True`, is a single value right?. Are you using empty values to test?.

Comment: the `many=True` on your SlugRelatedField serializer looks a little out of place with the code you've shared

Comment: @cabesuon using empty values to test also returns an invalid_value.

Comment: @henriquesalvaro  you are right, I've removed them. There is just one address associated with each origin and destination address.

Comment: couple of things to try, 1) change `SlugRelatedField` for `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` just to check it works, 2) add `allow_null=True` and `required=False` to the serializer, 3) change `pk` for `id` (yeah I know, it make no sense)

Comment: @cabesuon it works! Thanks a lot for your help. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Glad it helps! .. De nada ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by replacing `SlugRelatedField` to `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    originAddress = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Address.objects.all(), allow_null=True, required=False
    )
    destinationAddress = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Address.objects.all(), allow_null=True, required=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'packages', 'destinationAddress', 'originAddress')
```